# A module to generate a table automatically in perl

Tags: perl, oop

I have some content on my STDOUT and i want that content need to be arranged in to a descent table.

Can anyone suggest me a Perl module that does handle this kind of requirement

Thanks in Advance, any small help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Aditya

Comment: Just use `printf`. It's built-in, easy, and it works.

Comment: You would need to show the sort of data you are dealing with, and your required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Text::Table`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aTable) and [`Text::ASCIITable`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aASCIITable) make two different outputs, the latter having outlines. I'm sure there are more hanging around CPAN. You also might look at [formats](http://p3rl.org/form), a little-used bit of Perl functionality, meant for formatting reports.

Answer (score 0):

From CPAN, you can use [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTable)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to pipe the STDOUT from the existing program in to something else to format it, you can do something like this using printf

Create a perl script called process.pl

```
 #/bin/perl
use strict;

while (<>) {
    my $unformatted_input = $_;

    # Assuming you want to split on spaces, adjust if it is in fixed format.
    my @elements = split / +/, $unformatted_input, 4;

    # Printf format string, you can adjust lengths here.  This would take
    #  an input of items in the elements array and make each file 10 characters
    #  See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html for options
    my $format_string='%10s%10s%10s%10s';

    printf($format_string,@elements);
}
```

Then, pipe your STDOUT to this and it will format it to screen:

```
$  yourProcessThatDoesStdout | process.pl
```